# Your cluster version will expire in 14 days

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have this message on our production SF cluster but our next update cycle is a bit more than 30 days away. Will our current SF cluster continue to work as is for this period?

Answer (score 1):

I believe so, yes.

> 14 days prior to the expiry of the release your cluster is running, a health event is generated that puts your cluster into a warning health state. The cluster remains in a warning state until you upgrade to a supported fabric version.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade)